# How to use d3.js to animate a timeseries area graph (jsfiddle demo works, but looks weird )

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the d3.js to emulate a timeseries area graph on the temperature, for every second, the temperature array will shift the oldest value and push a newest value, and then render the graph with the temperature array.

the online demo is shown here.
 http://jsfiddle.net/qHUU7/

the online demo works that it updates the graph with transition, but if you looks at the animation closely, it is wield.

I want the timerseries graph to move the area shape from right to left on the x axis, much like http://square.github.io/cubism/, but my demo doesn't move the graph from right to left, but just update each value in the temperature value vertically.

I know the reason is because my code just render all the values each time. In order to move the area graph, I should use attr("transform", function(d){}), but I still don't figure out how to .

The following is my existing code

```
var colors = [  "#CDFADB","#75B8C1","#DD8BB9","#BA97C1","#ff6600"];
var randomcolors = d3.scale.category20();

var data2 = [ {v:3},{v:6},{v:7},{v:5},{v:2},{v:4},{v:8},{v:9},{v:1},{v:3},{v:8},{v:3},{v:6},{v:8},{v:1},{v:3},{v:8},{v:5},{v:2},{v:1}];

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 300]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([  d3.min( data2, function(d){return d.v;  }) - 1,
                                    d3.max( data2, function(d){return d.v;  }) + 1               
                                 ])
                         .range([0, 70]);

var y_position = 100;                        

var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg").attr("width", "600px").attr("height", "300px");
var statuslayer = graph.append("g").attr('id','statuslayer');

var rooms = [{name:'aa'},{name:'bb'}]
rooms.forEach(function(room){
    statuslayer.append('path')
               .attr('class','room room-'+room.name);   
})

var inter = setInterval(function() {    
    var updateData2 = function(){
        data2.shift();
        data2.push( {v: Math.random(1+10)*10} ); 
        var index = 0;
        var area = d3.svg.area()
            .interpolate("basis")
            .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
            .y0(function(d,i) { return 70+ y_position*index; })
            .y1(function(d,i) { return y(d.v) + y_position*index ; });  

        rooms.forEach(function(room){           
            d3.select('.room-'+room.name)
               .datum(data2)               
               .style("fill",function(){ return colors[index] })
               .transition().duration(400)
               .ease("linear")
               .attr("d", area);
            index +=1;
        })
    }
    updateData2();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: [This article](http://blog.visual.ly/creating-animations-and-transitions-with-d3-js/) may help.

Comment: Hi, Lars, I have seen this article. But it doesn't mention about how to animate the area graph based on path. If you have seen my code, I have made the animation already, but my problem is the animation is not moving from right to left. the rect example in the article seems similar to my requirement, but in fact it is still two different thing

Comment: This tutorial describes the problem and how to fix it: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

Comment: Somewhat late, but if you're still having problems check out my code here, it has a realtime series working. https://github.com/isadaqah/d3-realtime-timeseries, and here for a demo: http://sheetsync.net/monitor/